# Javascript boolean operation not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, session-storage

I have a really weird problem. I have an if statement like the such below:

```
$rootScope.changeView = function(view){
    $location.path(view); // path not hash
};

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
    console.log(next.requireLogin + " " + LoginService.getUserLoggedIn());
    console.log(next.requireLogin && !LoginService.getUserLoggedIn());

    if(next.requireLogin && !LoginService.getUserLoggedIn()) {
        console.log("No access to panel: not logged in.");

        alert("You need to be logged in as an administrator to see this page!");
        event.preventDefault();

        $timeout(function () {
            $rootScope.changeView("/");
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Where LoginServer.getUserLoggedIn and setUserLoggedIn are this:

```
this.setUserLoggedIn = function(value){
    sessionStorage.userIsLoggedIn = value;
};

this.getUserLoggedIn = function() {
    return sessionStorage.userIsLoggedIn;
};
```

The problem is simple. The If statement is never called, even when next.requireLogin is true and LoginService.getUserLoggedIn() is false. The output in the console is as follows:

```
true false
false
```

So apparently "next.requireLogin && !LoginService.getUserLoggedIn()" evaluates to false, yet both are the correct values? If it helps, in the Chrome console the last line with "false" is highlighted purple.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sessionStorage` stores strings, not booleans. So `getUserLoggedIn` returns the string `"true"` or `"false"`, and all non-empty strings are truthy.

Change `getUserLoggedIn` to return a boolean.

```
this.getUserLoggedIn = function() {
    return sessionStorage.userIsLoggedIn == 'true';
};
```

If you'd used `console.log(next.requireLogin, LoginService.getUserLoggedIn())` you would have seen the quotes around the second value, and maybe you'd have realized the problem. When you concatenate, you lose the type information.

Answer (score 1):

Because the value returned from session storage is a string and not a Boolean

```
console.log(!"false");
```

Either you need to compare to the string, or convert the string to a Boolean.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `LoginService.getUserLoggedIn()` returns "false", not boolean false. See the following snippet.

```js
var a="false";
console.log(a);//prints false
console.log(!a);//prints false as well.
```

So **replace**

`if(next.requireLogin && !LoginService.getUserLoggedIn()) {`

**with**

`if(next.requireLogin && (LoginService.getUserLoggedIn() == "false")) {`